# Laravel 5.7 : Trying to get property 'role' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, eloquent, syntax-error

I'm get :

> Trying to get property 'role' of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\pages\home.blade.php)

I created a project, there I created admin + user 'role' for login permissions and immediately redirected to home.blade.php.

in home.blade.php I add the following syntax :

```
@if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=admin">
@else
<p>Hello!</p>
@endif
```

My goal is for the **admin** to enter the home page and redirect to admin page, and the **user** to enter the home page only.

**My Problem is : If access home.blade.php *without* login, i get an error like this :**

> Trying to get property 'role' of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\pages\home.blade.php)

Comment: Have you logged in? What is in the `Auth::user()`?

Comment: Try to check like isset(Auth::user()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are not logged in, the user is null (a non-object).

You can account for this by checking to see if a user is logged in before attempting to access its attributes.

```php
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role === 'admin')
```